# Blender 2.8, Viewport objects visibility

Tags: 3d-view

I was making a tunnel model for animation, but somewhere I may have done something wrong and now the objects in the viewport are displaying with the background and foreground flipped. The objects which should be hidden from view are visible and the foreground objects are hidden

From "background"  I do not mean background images but objects[image]

Comment: hey, welcome to the community. Please add screenshots so we can better understand your situation.

Comment: I've added a screenshot....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select the object in question, go Edit mode, flip normals and leave Edit mode.
Check "Clip start" and "Clip end" of the View port camera (which not visible 
as an object...it is simply "there" :) ) which settings can be found on the right
side pane und View->View top most second and third entry.

Comment: Got it, it was the clipping.

Comment: In viewport rendering, I can't see the objects even with the lights present, they're all shown as transparent (I've set the background as transparent), that doesn't seem to be related to clipping. What could be the issue?

Comment: would you mind to post your file or the relevant part of it?

Comment: It's kind of happening in all of the objects. However, at the moment it seems it's not an issue anymore, if I come across it again I will reach out (or maybe play around with clipping if it's that).